# wxPython: refresh and update combobox

Tags: python, wxpython, refresh

I got a wxPython combobox which contains a list of sections of my .ini file.
I add new section while my program is running. And I also want to see the NEW entries in my combobox.

How can I refresh / update it?

My code :

```
self.cbxCfgProfiles = wx.ComboBox(self, pos=(170, 120), size=(440, -1),   
                                  choices=getCfgProfileList(), style=wx.CB_DROPDOWN)
```

When I restart my program I see the new entries.

I try already `self.cbxCfgProfiles.Refresh()` in my method. It does not work. :(

Comment: Do you want this list updated automatically? If not, have you considered adding an Update button and using the `wx.ComboBox.Clear()` and `wx.ComboBox.AppendItems` functions?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a new list of strings that you want to set the combobox to, the `SetItems()` method is probably the easiest way. It clears the control and then adds all the new selections.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I only worked with pyGtk until now, and one alternative for you it's to make a thread that verifies wheter there is a new section at your .ini file that isn't on a dict with the same values already loaded to your combobox and the items that wheren't on that dict you can insert them.
I think this will help:

```
wx.ComboBox.Insert()
```